# How to make import.io refresh Google Sheets automatically?

Tags: import.io, zapier

I used the Extractor to scrape my comments page at Hacker News. I used Export to Google Sheets. Then with Zapier I created a Zap to send me an email when a new row is added to the Google sheets.

I went back to HN and added a comment but my API was not updated with my comment. Then I ran the query by clicking on the Run query button and I saw that now the data was updated with my comment.

But Google sheets is not updating. How do I make the Google Sheets to update when a new comment is entered? What am I doing wrong?